# PHP serialize not working

Tags: php, javascript

I am getting input from a dynamic form (HTML+JavaScript) and extracting the data using a PHP script. I am using the `serialize` statement in PHP. This doesn't seem to be working - I am not able to get any data into the variables `$featureids` and `$featurenames` .

This is the code -

The HTML portion -

```
<table border = "1px" width = "700px">
    <tr width> <td>
    <b> Features </b> <br/> <br/>
    FeatureId: <input type = "text" name = "FirstFeatureId"> <br/>
    FeatureName: <input type = "text" name = "FirstFeatureName"> 
    <input type = "button" value = "Add Item" onclick = "addFeatureItem()" /> <br/>
    <span id = "features"> <br/> </span>
    </td> </tr>
</table>
```

The JavaScript method

```
function addFeatureItem(){
    //Text field to get the feature id 
    var featureIdTextField = document.createElement("input");
    featureIdTextField.setAttribute("name", "FeatureId[]");
    featureIdTextField.setAttribute("value", "Feature Id");

    var item = document.getElementById("features");
    item.appendChild(featureIdTextField);

    //Text field to get the feature name
    var featureNameTextField = document.createElement("input");
    featureNameTextField.setAttribute("name", "FeatureName[]");

    //Insert a break statement after creating a feature id and name
    var breakStatement = document.createElement("br");

    item.appendChild(featureNameTextField);
    item.appendChild(breakStatement);

}
```

and the PHP portion -

```
$featureids = serialize($_POST["FeatureId"]);
echo $featureids;
$featureids = unserialize($featureids);

//inserting all the feature ids into an array
$featureIdArray = array($_POST["FirstFeatureId"]);
foreach ($featureids as $featureid) {
    echo $featureid ;
    array_push($featureIdArray, $featureid);
}

$featurenames = serialize($_POST["FeatureName"]);
$featurenames = unserialize($featurenames);

//insert all the feature names into an array
$featureNameArray = array($_POST["FirstFeatureName"]);
foreach ($featurenames as $featurename) {
    array_push($featureNameArray, $featurename);
}
```

**EDIT** -
This is the form data in Networks->Headers in Chrome

```
FirstFeatureId:fid
FirstFeatureName:fname
FeatureId[]:Feature Id
FeatureName[]:Feature Name
FeatureId[]:Feature Id
FeatureName[]:Feature Name
FeatureId:
```

Note - The very last FeatureId is empty for some reason

Comment: Why you trying to serialize and unserialize?

Comment: Also turn on all errors and explore your error.log file

Comment: The only Warning in the error.log is `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: we don't see the form in your piece of HTML..

Comment: `$_POST["FeatureId"]` has value?

Comment: yes, try to echo your `£_POST['FeatureId']` before serialize it

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code povided that the form tags are outside the table and you're adding the text fields to an element that is inside the form. If you have Firefox and Firebug you can inspect the post values in the net tab. In chrome it's under the network tab and post is under "form data" after clicking on the php file in the "name path" column. Open the dev tools by pressing F12

Comment: I have just added the form input that is being passed to the PHP script. I obtained this by looking in the Networks tab in Chrome

Comment: @MatRt - That is also not printing anything

Comment: Off-topic, you should consider using names like feature[0][id] and feature[0][name] so your data in php is associated.  You could then do something like `foreach ($_POST['feature'] as $feature) { echo $feature['id']; echo $feature['name']; }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is some where around here

```
var featureIdTextField = document.createElement("input");
featureIdTextField.setAttribute("name", "FeatureId[]");
featureIdTextField.setAttribute("value", "Feature Id");
```

try to log these FeatureId and FirstFeatureName, I am sure these are empty

other wise there is no problem with the serialize and unserealize functions.

Also why dont you use jQuery to create new element